# Problem rendering scene

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I have an animation almost completed, and wanted to start taking some records of it.

Problem is that when on camera view, some projects have problems. Here's a screenshot of one:

[image]

I'm using blender Render

Another problem I'm getting with this is that, if there's a plane near another, it also gets the problem I described above (Like roads and grass, even if the road is few inches above in Z)

---

I've fixed this problem. Main reason was that Mirror wasnt applied :( Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe it's a bug with a modifier on either of your meshes. That's possible. What are all the mesh based modifiers on those distorted spheres?

Comment: I have mirror in it (they are on top of a building, which I only modeled half). Could it be it?

Comment: Quite possibly. In the second sphere it appears that only half of it appears destroyed. Particularly, the mirrored half. Check to make sure that none of the values on the mirror modifier are invalid. If that does not work, try applying the modifier if you can to convert the mirrored half to a mesh. I am assuming it has not already been applied. There's some things to try for you. Good luck!

Comment: @Cafn Can you attach the blend file?

Comment: I've fixed this problem. Main reason was that Mirror wasnt applied :( Thanks for the help!